# java: nested class definitions - name collision or not? (OCPJP)

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

I created this test problem seeing how a lot of OCPJP questions about inner classes have what looks like purposeful name collisions. Question: how would I ever create an instance of the A class that has id = 1.

```
class A{ int id = 1; }

class Bag {
    static class A{ int id = 2; }
    }

public class InnerClasses
    {   
    static class A{ int id = 3; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    A A1 = new A(); 
    Bag.A A2 = new Bag.A();
    A A3 = new A();

    System.out.println(A1.id); //prints 3
    System.out.println(A2.id); //prints 2
    System.out.println(A3.id); //prints 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define class A in a separate java file named A and instantiate it by calling the constructor with the full package name. Like this:

```
com.mypackage.A A1 = new com.mypackage.A(); 
Bag.A A2 = new Bag.A();
A A3 = new A();

System.out.println(A1.id); //prints 1
System.out.println(A2.id); //prints 2
System.out.println(A3.id); //prints 3
```

Although the point of defining an inner class with the same name would only be in order to override the definition of the other class. So it kind of beats the point...